# FB.api not working every time

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am new to Facebook Javascript SDK. I am trying to create an application using this API. But has hard luck while usign the FB.api method. Somehow my FB.api method is not working properly each time. Sometimes it will give the response (I am just accessing response.name) while other time it will not invoked properly.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'my_app_id', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
   alert('user is:'+response.status); 
   userId = response.authResponse.userID;
   FB.api('/me',function(response) {
   alert('Inside FB.api function');
   document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML = 'Welcome <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' +response.name + '!';
    });
    }
});
};
```

Other methods FB.ui and FB.getLoginStatus and Facebook like button is working as expected, but only FB.api is not working seamless manner as others. Do not why? Please help me to idenify the problem.

Comment: :/ please format your post in such a way that people can easily read it...

Comment: what errors do you get when you call `FB.api('/me')`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. This answer pointed me into the right direction:

[FB.api does not work when called right after FB.init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494280/fb-api-does-not-work-when-called-right-after-fb-init)

To solve my problem I had to subscribe to the correct event. In my case it was 'auth.authResponseChange' after FB.init

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(){
    FB.api('/me',function(r){
    console.log(r.id);
     if (!r || r.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        alert(r.name);
      }         
    });
});
```

Comment: Something else I also noticed. FB.api fails if I modify the DOM before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

That code works fine for me, but you might want to try renaming your response variables. Inside the FB.api callback, you actually have two response variables which will undoubtedly cause problems. Try changing them and see if you get different results.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(loginResponse) {
  if (loginResponse.authResponse) {
   alert('user is:'+loginResponse.status); 
   userId = loginResponse.authResponse.userID;
   FB.api('/me',function(apiResponse) {
   alert('Inside FB.api function');
   document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML = 'Welcome <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ apiResponse.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' +apiResponse.name + '!';
    });
    }
});
```

Its possible there is something else on your page affecting this. Do you have a link to your page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Abby. I will try to edit the response variable and let you know. I am developing application locally right now.

Comment: Still no luck. I have tried to change the variable name and the script is behaving the same way.

Comment: Ok. What is actually happening when it fails? Do you get an error message? Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: Nope, It is working in my local environment and not published over the net yet. It did not give me any javascript error message or any other error message. I have also tried to remove everything from my file expect the code above and div(userInfo). I have also tried the same thing with fbrell.com javascript tool which also fails to show the user information. One thing I can see in the status bar of browser, that when it tries to call the FB.api method several call are made to URL graph.facebook.com with connected to and connecting to prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. FB.api just stopped working silently at some point in my app. I noticed it was due to a DOM manipulation of :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Either a duplication or anything. You should check that point. It looks like Johan Strydom's problem.