# FB.api does not work when called right after FB.init

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

FB.api does not work when called right after FB.init. Here is the code snippet I use:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId : window.APP_ID,
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth : true,
    channelUrl : window.MASTER_URL + "channel",
    frictionlessRequests : true
  });

  window.COMPANY.init();
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

And here is my COMPANY.init() and COMPANY.fetchAllFriends():

```
friends: new Array(),

init : function() {
  // TODO

  COMPANY.fetchAllFriends();

  FB.Canvas.setSize($(document).height());
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
},    

fetchAllFriends : function() {
  FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      return;
    }

    COMPANY.friends = new Array();
    $.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
      COMPANY.friends.push(value.id);
    });
  });
},
```

where at fetchAllFriends response contains error which says "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.". I made sure (via the browsers debugger) that FB.init is called before that call of FB.api.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I fixed my problem. I changed:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId : window.APP_ID,
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth : true,
    channelUrl : window.MASTER_URL + "channel",
    frictionlessRequests : true
  });

  window.COMPANY.init();
};
```

to:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId : window.APP_ID,
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth : true,
    channelUrl : window.MASTER_URL + "channel",
    frictionlessRequests : true
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', window.COMPANY.init);
};
```

in case anyone else want to know. What I found is that the FB JS SDK has not formed the user session by the time when FB.init returns, so what you need to do is to subscribe to the 'auth.login' event with your init function. More info [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be checking the status of the user. All you are doing is initializing Facebook, you don't even know if the user is logged into Facebook or has a Facebook account. You need to call FB.getLoginStatus and check if they are "connected". If they aren't connected, there is no possible way to get an access token. If they are connected, then you get an access token.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't explain why the 'fetchAllFriends' method (as defined above) works perfectly, when called after page is loaded, without explicitly calling FB.getLoginStatus or putting a token in the call...

Comment: Forgot to mention that my app is embedded in a Facebook canvas page and is behind a dispatch page that authenticates the user, so at the time the above methods are called, it is made sure that the user is logged in Facebook.

Comment: I would still suggest calling getLoginStatus and putting anything you need run in the callback for that function. That assures everything is ready. But if you don't want to do that, then I would suggest using FB.Event.subscribe. Perhaps subscribing to auth.statusChange. Even though you have a dispatch page, Facebook still needs to check the user status. Facebook doesn't know there was a dispatch page.

Comment: +1 for your attempt to help me :)) Although, I fixed the problem yesterday and the solution is posted above